# How to use partition to select only the desired row?

Tags: sql, select

Here is my table:

```
table1:
id_nbr                 op_nbr
123E0100               HTM
123E0102               FO
145E0102               HTM
145E0104               FO
198E0100               HTM
234E0100               JAV
234E0102               FO
```

I need to select `123E0102` and `145E0104` from the field `id_nbr`.

For both of them, there exists an `id_nbr` that matches on the first 6 characters. `op_nbr` associated with the original `id_nbr` are `HTM`.
The last 2 characters increment by 2.

I'm trying to retrieve all rows where the first 6 characters are equal and last 2 characters are 02 higher than the value in the row where there is `HTM` in `op_nbr` field.

Comment: What is your desired output?  I can't quite follow the description of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about `partition` do you mean Windowed Aggregate Functions?

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT t.*
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN op_nbr =  'HTM' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(id_nbr FROM 7) AS INT) END)
       OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(id_nbr FROM 1 FOR 6)) AS id_HTM
      ,MIN(CASE WHEN op_nbr <> 'HTM' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(id_nbr FROM 7) AS INT) END)
       OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(id_nbr FROM 1 FOR 6)) AS id_other
   FROM table1 AS t
 ) AS dt
WHERE op_nbr <> 'HTM'
  AND id_other = id_HTM + 2
```

You could also apply this logic using EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE op_nbr <> 'HTM'
  AND EXISTS
   ( -- check if the "previous" row matches 'HTM'
     SELECT * FROM table1 AS t2
     WHERE SUBSTRING(t1.id_nbr FROM 1 FOR 6) = SUBSTRING(t2.id_nbr FROM 1 FOR 6)
       AND t2.op_nbr ='HTM'
       AND CAST(SUBSTRING(t1.id_nbr FROM 7) AS INT) =
           CAST(SUBSTRING(t2.id_nbr FROM 7) AS INT) + 2
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use window functions for this, an aggregation and a join seems a more natural fit.  Use the aggregation to get the row with the id on the htm row.  Then use a `join` to get the rows with a bigger number:

```
select t1.*
from (select left(t1.id_nbr, 6),
             max(case when t1.op_nbr = 'HTM' then t1.id_nbr end) as htm_id
      from table1 t1
      group by left(t1.id_nbr, 6)
     ) tt1 join
     table1 t1
     on left(t1.id_nbr, 6) = left(tt1.id_nbr, 6) and
        tt1.id_nbr > htm_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select * from TableName t1
where exists(select * from TableName t2 
             where left(t1.id_nbr) = left(t2.id_nbr) and
             t2.op_nbr = 'htm' and
             right(t2.id_nbr) = right(t1.id_nbr) - 2)
```